# Facebook graph limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been reading through the Facebook Doc's about limits of requests to their graph api (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting). It states there are 200 calls allowed per user per hour ( e.g If app has 10 users Facebook allows 10x200 = 2000 calls to the api per hour).

Facebook states:

> Rate limiting is done on your Facebook AppId. If your app reaches a
>   rate limit, all calls made for that app will be limited not just on a
>   per-user basis.

So I have a concern that one malicious user can use up all 2000 calls in an hour and my app would be down since users can't make calls anymore. Is there a way to stop a user from making so many calls?

Comment: For server-side API calls, you can define a whitelist of IPs requests are allowed from. Plus, you can require that the appsecret_proof is mandatory for such calls, see also https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests/

Answer (score 1):

How would one user who can only do 200 API calls in an hour concern you? Because as you can read in the docs, it is `200 API calls per user`. That does not mean that one user can use 2000 calls just because there are 10 users in the App. And i am sure that Facebook will not punish any App just because one single user gets to the limit all the time. That would allow a competitor to just stop your App from working instantly, all the time.